# Spring AOP @RequestBody interfering with @Configurable

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration

I am working on a Spring project using 3.2.3.RELEASE and cannot get the dependency injection to work with a non-spring managed object. Specifically using an object as below using `@Configurable`.

```
@Configurable
public class DomainObject
{
    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    private String name;

    public void testDependencies()
    {
        if(messageService != null)
            System.out.println("...");
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("...");
    }
 }
```

The spring configuration is purely annotation driven with no xml outside of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>Test AOP Configuration</display-name>
 <servlet>
       <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>com.test.configuration</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the `MvcConfiguration.class`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
   public ViewResolver getViewResolver()
   {
       InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return resolver;
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
   {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }

   ...remaining bean definitions
```

Everything seemed to be working until I tried to use this object in a `Controller`. It autowires correctly as long as the controller mapping does not contain `DomainObject` as a `@RequestBody` parameter of the controller mapping.

This example works perfectly, everything deserializes and the message service is injected as I expected.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
   public ModelAndView test(@RequestParam String id, @RequestBody String json) throws IOException
   {
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      System.out.println("id = " + id);
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      try
      {
         JsonUtility.readValue(json, DomainObject.class).testDependencies();
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
         exception.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      try
      {
         new DomainObject().testDependencies();
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
         exception.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      return new ModelAndView("home");
   }
}
```

This however is what I originally intended and neither the object passed in or the object created with new has its dependencies injected.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
   public ModelAndView test(@RequestParam String id, @RequestBody DomainObject domainObject) throws IOException
   {
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      System.out.println("id = " + id);
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      try
      {
         domainObject.testDependencies();
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
         exception.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      try
      {
         new DomainObject().testDependencies();
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
         exception.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(StringSupport.repeatString("*", 120, ""));
      return new ModelAndView("home");
   }
}
```

Any insight at all into either the `@RequestBody` deserialization process or the `@Configurable` aspect through would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide the exception trace that you get back also.

Comment: No stack trace comes from Spring or the App Server, the DomainObject just gets created with the @Autowired messageService == null.